# ASP.NET Core MVCでの非同期Validation

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC（C# .NET 5）で構築したWebアプリケーションにおいてユーザー入力チェックを行いたいと考えています。

単純な入力チェックはModelの検証機能を用いたValidationAttributeを用いることで非常に簡単に行うことができます。しかしDatabaseアクセスを伴うようなValidationAttributeを作った場合、ASP.NET Core MVCには非同期Validationの仕組みがありません。どのような対応方法を取るのが適切でしょうか。

以下３案は思いついた案ですが、もっと適切な方法があるのではないかと考えています。

1. Validationの場合はDatabaseアクセスも同期処理として実装する
   　　`AnyAsync()`, `ToListAsync()`などを用いず、`Any()`, `ToList()`を用いる
2. 非同期処理を待つ

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as SomeModel;
    var domainService = validationContext.GetService<IMyDomainService>();
    var task = domainService.SomeCheckAsync(model);
    Task.WaitAll(task);
    var result = task.Result;
    if (!result)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessageString));
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

3. Taskで実行

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as SomeModel;
    var domainService = validationContext.GetService<IMyDomainService>();
    var result = Task.Run(() => {
        return domainService.SomeCheckAsync(model);
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (!result)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessageString));
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

いまいち煮え切らないのは下記のように考えたからです。

1. ASP.NET Coreは非同期処理を使うことでブロッキングが発生せずに適切なパフォーマンスで動作するという基本設計に反していると思いました。Micorosoft技術者のBlogで同期と非同期を混在させるべきではないとの記載もあったかと思います。
2. おそらくデッドロックが発生するのではないか（お試しでは発生していない）。
3. ASP.NETの通常の処理でTask.Run()を使うのはご法度とどこかで読んだ気がするのですが…探せませんでした。

個人的に、ModelのAnnotationとして設定することができるData Annotation Model Validatorは、ビジネスロジックと分離した検証機構として非常に優れた設計だと考えていますので、ビジネスロジックとして入力チェックを行う案はできる限り避けたいと考えています（そうするのが適切なら、そうするしかないですが）。

Comment: ASP.NET で非同期プログラミングを行う目的は、スレッドプールにある限られた数のスレッドを有効利用し、スループットを向上するためです。GUI の目的（UI 応答性の向上）とは違うことは認識してますか？　それから、ASP.NET Core アプリでは Task.Result を使った同期コードと非同期コードを混在させても、.NET Framework 版の MVC5 アプリのようにデッドロックは起こらなかったです（理由不明）。参考記事⇒ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/01/02/aspnet-core-31-mvc-async-programing.aspx

Comment: サーバー側の検証だけの話ですよね？　そこを明確にしてください。あと、具体的に何を検証したいのかによっていろいろ話は変わってくるかと思いますので、そのあたりも明確にしてください。データアノテーション属性を使わないやり方も色々あります。DB がらみだとさらにこういう例もあります⇒ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/03/25/aspnet-core-validation-for-pk-and-unique-restrictions-of-sql-server.aspx

Comment: 上に書いた 2 つのコメントを見て、ご自分の質問内容を見直していただけませんか。

Comment: WebSurferさんありがとうございます。サーバー側の検証だけの話になります。コメントと記事を検討して質問を見直します。

Comment: 「スレッドプールにある限られた数のスレッドを有効利用」も理解しているつもりです。DBアクセス中にスレッドを占有せずに、他のリクエスト用に有効活用するためには、DBアクセスは非同期にした方が良いとの理解です。

Comment: 自分が調べた限りですが、ValidationAttribute クラスを定義したカスタム検証属性では IsValid メソッドが非同期をサポートしていないのは確かなようです。と言って質問者さんがやったように Task.Run を使って本来の目的（スループットの向上）が果たせるかは分かりません。そこにこだわって調べるのに時間を使うより、普通にアクションメソッドで検証する方が良さそうです。他にカスタムモデルバインダを定義して使うという方法もありそうですが、そこまでやる必要性もなさそうな気がします。その 2 案で良ければ紹介しますがどうですか？

Comment: 本筋とは別の話ですが、ASP.NET Coreでデッドロックが発生しなかった理由は右記のリンクの回答（Stephen Cleary氏のもの）にありそうです。  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007006/is-getawaiter-getresult-safe-for-general-use#comment85070745_39007110

Comment: それはASP.NET Core でデッドロックにならない理由とは思えません。何にせよ Microsoft のドキュメントに見つからないかぎり想像の域を出ませんので、同期/非同期は混在させないというガイドラインは守った方が良さそうです。先のコメントの「その 2 案で良ければ紹介しますがどうですか？ 」に返事がないですが、不用ということと理解します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。カスタムモデルバインダについては、私も検証のためだけにそこまでやるには、よほどスマートな実装方法を自分が思いつかない限りしなくてもいいかなと思っています。アクションメソッドで検証する方法は、自分で解決できると考えておりますので、WabSurferさんのお手を煩わせる必要はないかと思っています。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 自分で解決できるとのことですので、いつまでもこのスレッドを放置しておかないで、あなたの解決策を書いてクローズしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問に対するコメント欄で「いつまでもこのスレッドを放置しておかないで、あなたの解決策を書いてクローズしてください」とお願いしたのですがやってもらえないので私が書いておきます。

ASP.NET アプリでは Web サーバーがクライアントから要求を受けるとスレッドプールからスレッドを確保して要求を処置します。非同期操作をしなければ、要求を受けてから応答を返すまで最初に確保したスレッドを保持し続けます。

IO バウンドの処理 (外部データベースや Web API などにアクセスしてデータを取得するなど) に時間がかかる場合は一旦使っていたスレッドはスレッドプールに戻し、IO バウンドの処理が終わったらスレッドプールから新たにスレッドを取得してその後の処理を行うようにすればスレッドプールのスレッドの有効利用が可能です。

そのあたりの詳細は以下の Microsoft のドキュメントに図解入りで説明されているので見てください。

ASP.NET の非同期/待機の概要
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net

> 1. Validationの場合はDatabaseアクセスも同期処理として実装する

上に書いた理由で IO バウンドの処理を行う場合は非同期を考えるべきで、データアノテーション属性を使いたいから非同期処理を諦めるというのは考え直した方が良さそうです。

例えば、コントローラーでユーザー入力を処理する過程でデータベースアクセスして検証できるなら、その過程で検証すれば非同期で処理できます。

以下の記事はその例です。データベースにあるデータとの重複を避けるために PK / Unique 制約違反例外をキャッチし、重複していたら差し戻しエラーメッセージを表示して再入力を促すようにしています。

EF Core で PK / Unique 制約違反例外をキャッチ
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/03/25/aspnet-core-validation-for-pk-and-unique-restrictions-of-sql-server.aspx

> 2. 非同期処理を待つ

以下の Microsoft のドキュメントの Avoid blocking calls のセクションを見てください (日本語版もありますが翻訳がアレですので英語版を読むことをお勧めします)。

ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-6.0

やってはいけないこととして以下のように書いてあります。

"Block asynchronous execution by calling Task.Wait or Task.Result."

> 3. Taskで実行

これも同じ Microsoft のドキュメントにやってはいけないこととして以下のように書いてあります。

"Call Task.Run and immediately await it. ASP.NET Core already runs app code on normal Thread Pool threads, so calling Task.Run only results in extra unnecessary Thread Pool scheduling. Even if the scheduled code would block a thread, Task.Run does not prevent that."

以上のような訳で、私の回答は「**検証にデーターベースへのアクセスが必要ならデータアノテーション属性の使用にこだわる必要はなく、上の 1 に対するレスで書いた通りコントローラーその他非同期処理が容易に可能な過程で行えばよい**」です。

Comment: 詳しい解説ありがとうございます。質問を閉じていない理由としては、Action Methodの中でチェックを行うという解決策以外のアイデアが無いか求めているためです。データアノテーション属性に拘っているというよりは、Action Method外で検証を行う仕組みが作れることが理想です（「ビジネスロジックとして入力チェックを行う案はできる限り避けたいと考えています」というのはそういうことです）。

Comment: 先に「カスタムモデルバインダを定義して使うという方法もありそうです」と言いましたが、それもあなたの理想ではない？　2 ヵ月も誰もレスしないということは少なくともここではアイデアは出ないと思います。クローズして他の Q&A サイトで質問すべき。待っていたと言ってますけど、私の最後のコメントは無視でしたし、こちらから見ればスレッドの放置・放棄ですよ。

Comment: ちなみに、クライアント側の検証だけで良ければ RemoteAttribute というのがあります。検証用のアクションメソッドを作り、クライアント側からそれを呼び出して検証を行うものです。サーバー側での実装は考えられてないですが、たぶん普通にデータをアクションメソッドで処理する過程で検証すれば良いと考えてのことだと想像してます。具体例は: http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2022/02/11/client-side-validation-using-remoteattribute.aspx

Comment: カスタムモデルバインダで解決する案については、新しい検証の仕組みを作るということになると思いますが、この理解で合っているでしょうか？参考までに、この件に関する問題意識としては、リンク先の ilmaxさんと同じです。https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/786

Comment: 色々とアイデアをありがとうございます。クライアント検証を行っても、サーバー側での検証が免除されるわけではないので、そこの部分については、今のところ考えていません。

Comment: カスタムモデルバインダを使ってその中で検証は非同期でできるというだけです。アクションメソッドで検証しないことにこだわるなら残るはそれぐらいということで、上にも書いたように推奨しているわけではありません。RemoteAttribute の件は、クライアント側の検証でそういうものが用意されているのに、サーバー側には無いことが何を意味するのか考えてみてはということです。

Comment: 2 ヵ月も誰もレスがなかったということは少なくともここではもうあなたが期待するアイデアは出ないと思います。クローズして他の Q&A サイトで質問すべき。イイカゲンにしてください。